# Утечка памяти в каком-то месте самодельного вектора

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Сделал простенький вектор, все мои тесты проходит, но окаянное онлайн-тестирование кидает в меня ошибкой "Memory leak detected". Помогите найти места, где может быть утечка памяти. Я думаю, виноват pushBack, но все же в конце приложу полную версию кода, вдруг не он.

pushBack:

```
void PushBack(const T& value) {
        T* result;

        if (Array == nullptr) {
            result = new T[1];
            Array = result;
            end_ = Array + 1;
        }
        else if (arSize == (*this).Capacity()) {
            size_t capacity = (*this).Capacity() * 2;
            T* result = new T[capacity];


            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arSize; ++i)
                result[i] = Array[i];

            Array = result;
            end_ = Array + capacity;

        }

        Array[arSize++] = value;
    }
```

Все имеющиеся переменные:

```
private:
T* Array;
T* end_;
unsigned int arSize = 0;
```

**Весь код:**

```
`template <typename T>
class SimpleVector {
public:
    SimpleVector() {
        Array = nullptr;
        end_ = Array;
    }

    explicit SimpleVector(size_t size) : Array(new T[size]), end_(Array + size){
        arSize += size;
    }

    ~SimpleVector() {
        delete[] Array;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) {
        return Array[index];
    }

    T* begin() {
        return Array;
    }

    T* end() {
        return end_;
    }

    size_t Size() const {
        return arSize;
    }

    size_t Capacity() const {
        return end_ - Array;
    }

    void PushBack(const T& value) {
        T* result;

        if (Array == nullptr) {
            result = new T[1];
            Array = result;
            end_ = Array + 1;
        }
        else if (arSize == (*this).Capacity()) {
            size_t capacity = (*this).Capacity() * 2;
            T* result = new T[capacity];


            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arSize; ++i)
                result[i] = Array[i];

            Array = result;
            end_ = Array + capacity;

        }

        Array[arSize++] = value;
    }

private:
    T* Array;
    T* end_;
    unsigned int arSize = 0;

};`
```

Comment: при реалокации вы не освобождаете память

Comment: T* result = new T[capacity];
Array = result;
В этом месте утечет вся память ранее выделенная под Array

Comment: Всё верно, в `PushBack` в ветке `else if` нужен `delete`.

Comment: Т.е перед `Array = result;` поставить `delete[] Array;`?

Comment: `unsigned int arSize = 0;` - и с чего это вдруг тут использован инициализатор, хотя ни для каких других полей такой инициализатор не используется?

Comment: В чем смысл метода `end()`? Кому и зачем нужен такой `end()`, если он возвращает конец capacity, а не конец size?

Comment: Зачем нужна переменная `result`, объявленная в начале `PushBack`? Зачем она там объявлена?

Comment: Первые два вопроса - это были ошибки, уже исправил их, а result мы присваиваем новый массив, в который копируем прошлый

Comment: @Vakarine: Переменная `result` для нового массива у вас объявлена локально внутри ветки `if`. Еще раз: зачем нужна переменная `result`, объявленная в начале `PushBack`???

Comment: Да, действительно, не усмотрел, планировалось, чтобы оно было как в при `Array == nullptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего в таких случаях использовать профайлер. Я взял ваш код, в `main()` создал экземляр `SimpleVector<int>`, добавил несколько вызовов `PushBack` и прогнал через свой Deleaker.

Вот что получилось:

[image: утечки]

Строка 46, это вот тут:

```
void PushBack(const T& value) {
    T* result;

    if (Array == nullptr) {
        result = new T[1];
```

52-я - вот эта:

```
  else if (arSize == (*this).Capacity()) {
        size_t capacity = (*this).Capacity() * 2;
      T* result = new T[capacity];
```

Ошибка в том, что когда выделяется память под новый массив большего размера, память, выделенная под старый массив, не освобождается после копирования старых элементов в новый массив.

Ещё один момент, который мне кажется не очень правильным, это политика увеличения размера - он удваивается. Не будет ли слишком большим рост? Традиционно применяют линейный рост.

Comment: При увеличении размера на два сложность будет амортизированной константой. А проблему уже решил, но все равно спасибо, программу посмотрю. Просто я там запутался: мы присваиваем в result указатели из предыдущего вектора, так если мы через delete[] удалим предыдущий вектор, должны ведь удалиться эти указатели => и в result они тоже удалятся, почему они не удалились?